# In the Hypothesis testing library, what is the real difference between assume and filter?

Tags: python, testing, fuzzing, python-hypothesis

Within the Hypothesis testing library for Python, there is the "[`assume`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/details.html#hypothesis.assume)" function, which "marks the example as bad, rather than failing the test". If there are too many "bad" examples generated in a row, Hypothesis, by default, will error out that test.

Within Hypothesis, there is a function that can be chained with Strategies named "[`filter`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#filtering)" that, well, filters out unwanted  generated data. If there are too many filtered data items generated in a row, Hypothesis, by default, will error out with the same kind of error as `assume`.

From the an example of `assume` from the docs:

```
@given(lists(integers()))
def test_sum_is_positive(xs):
    assume(len(xs) > 10)
    assume(all(x > 0 for x in xs))
    print(xs)
    assert sum(xs) > 0
```

Reimagined with `filter`:

```
@given(
    lists(
        integers().filter(lambda x: x > 0)
    ).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 10)
)
def test_sum_is_positive_filter(xs):
    print(xs)
    assert sum(xs) > 0
```

Are these essentially the same thing? I understand that the example may be a bit contrived, for educational purposes; they have been shrunk, as it were. If this is the case I just need to have my imagination stretched. (Note: running these two snippets on my Mac Ventura, the first fails a health check and the second one runs)

> What is the real, practical difference between these two functions?

> When should I use `assume` instead of `filter`?

Is there a performance difference between the two?

I searched through the Hypothesis repo to see if `assume` and `filter` were actually the same thing under the hood, and they *seemed* not to be.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @BlueRobin, how 'bout that? The specific problem is knowing the difference between these two scenarios I've added. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hey, I'm just trying to make sure you don't receive downvotes. The two questions: *"What is the real, practical difference between these two functions"* and *"When should I use the `assume` instead of `filter`"* are two separate questions. This may be seen as unfocused and the question might get closed. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they're essentially the same thing - rejection sampling.

However, there's an important difference in practice: `s.filter()` allows Hypothesis to reject *part* of an example and try again (within limits!), whereas `assume()` has to throw away the whole test case and start over.

If we ignore all the heuristics, runtime feedback, splicing, etc. for the sake of illustration... if we generate length-five lists from `s = lists(booleans())` we will have (let's say) a 0.5^5 = ~3% chance of satisfying `assume(all(s.example()))`.  However, we have (let's say) a 9/10 chance of satisfying `booleans().filter(bool)` thanks to internal retries, so applying the filter to elements makes it *much* more likely (~60%) we'll create a list of elements we're happy with.